# Algorithm returns the element of order k

Tags: algorithm

We are given the function β-select(A) that gives as an output the position of the floor(n/β)-th element in time Θ(n), where n is the number of elements of A.

I want to write an algorithm that returns the element of order k, 1<=k<=n of A in time Θ(n).

Could we maybe do it as follows?

We pick p = β-select(A) and this will be the position where the floor(n/b)-th element is and then we compare  p with k and if k < p ,we are looking for the desired element in the interval  [1,p-1] , if it is greater then at the iterval [p+1,n], otherwise we return p?

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is an integer.

Comment: And beta-select can be called for any array, not necessarily the initial one?

Comment: I assume so, but I don't know... Why?

Answer (score 0):

Let's always use beta = 2. Let's assume that beta select has returned p. We can split the original array into three parts: all elements less than A[p], all elements equal to A[p] and those that are greater than A[p]. We know in which part the element of order k is located(just by looking at the size of the first and second parts). If it is located in the second part, the answer is A[p]. Otherwise we can solve it recursively for either the first or the third part. The time complexity is O(n + n / 2 + n / 4 + ...) = O(n).